# How to run this MATLAB's command in R language?

Tags: r, matlab

```
file=[dir,'/',filename];
fop=fopen(file,'rb');
[values, count]=fread(fop,[4969, 2137],'float');
values=values';
fclose(fop);
```

I am running this command to read a binary file in MATLAB which contained 2137 rows and 4969 columns. But unable to read same file in R language.
I tried this command to run same process:

```
jo<-file(choose.files(),"rb")
jo2<-readBin(jo,double(),n=c(4969,2137),size=4,endian = "little")
```

But It only read the first row. 
Can anyone give me any suggestions to perform matlab's equivalent command in R to read file same as matlab.

Comment: I think `n` in `readBin` has to be an integer. You can read all `4969x2137` elements as a 1D array,then reshape it to `4969x2137` .

Comment: @Aziz is right. `n` refers to the total number of records, so you need `n = 10618753`, so that I think you should be able to create your desired object via `matrix(readBin(jo, double(), n = 10618753, size = 4, endian = "little"), nrow = 2137, ncol = 4969)`

Comment: Guys, post answers as answers, not comments